# In Sibelius ManuScript language example, why will the Run method not run?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, software, beginner, sibelius

I am learning to write Sibelius plug-ins by working my way through the **ManuScript Language Reference** (*see File > Plug-ins > ManuScript Language Reference*). Unlike other scripting languages I use (e.g. Xcode, Unix and Linux shell scripts, js), ManuScript is music-specific and the Sibelius documentation is excellent and easy to follow. However I hit a snag editing code in the **Run** method, using this code snippet on p.7

[image: code snippet]

Still in Edit mode, I clicked the **Check Syntax** button. It displayed the following message '`the syntax is correct`' and when I exit **Edit** mode and run the **Run** method, the following appeared

```
    Message ‘1 + 1 = 2” 
    OK
```

I closed the three dialogs by clicking OK, OK again then Close. When I ran the amended plug-in, Sibelius crashed. On the MacBook Pro I got the rolling rainbow beach-ball and the (MacOS) message

```
    Sibelius (not responding)
```

When I force quit Sibelius the message in the **Run** window remained until I clicked OK. At which point, the beach ball disappears but Sibelius appears to be still running (i.e. it can perform its normal non-scripted commands). Each time I try the above steps it crashes. I also tried it with `x` as a parameter in the **Edit** dialogue but this made no difference.

This looks like a bug but perhaps someone can kindly tell me if I have misunderstood something. Thanks.

---

Note. Tags I used for this question are not ideal but are the most appropriate available to me.

---

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the rolling beach ball appears on a Mac it normally means a program has crashed. However while using ManuScript to edit a plug-in, the same beach ball seems to appear whenever the mouse is not in the relevant place. It immediately disappears whenever the mouse hovers over the ManuScript Message window. So this might be the normal behaviour in the ManuScript language.

Moreover, I progressed through the rest of the examples in the ManuScript Language Reference without incident so until I am told otherwise I will treat the rolling beach ball as a window status indicator while editing. It appears only when the mouse hovers over the wrong window.

---

NOTE. There's a better answer out there. It'll help other novices if I wait for it.

---

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to relate to the Run method. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Aaron, I don't think you misunderstood the question. It's more a case of the answer not being one I initially expected. I tried to clarify the wording of the answer.

Comment: Got it. Helpful if you'd accept the answer then, so it's clear you found what you needed.